# shape C not found in the files.csv (tikz-network package)

Tags: packages, csv, edge

Following the first example on page 33 of https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network/blob/master/manual.pdf I have been getting the following error below.

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named C is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 ... layer={1,2},style=dashed]{data/ml_edges.csv}

?
```

Did I write something wrong in the code or omit something?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[multilayer=3d]
\Edges[vertices=data/ml_vertices.csv, layer={1,2},style=dashed]{data/ml_edges.csv}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**`ml_vertices.csv`**

```
id, x, y ,size,color,opacity,label,layer
 A, 0,  0, .4 , green,  .9   ,  a  ,  1
 B, 1, .7, .6 ,      ,  .5   ,  b  ,  1
 C, 2,  1, .8 ,orange,  .3   ,  c  ,  1
 D, 2,  0, .5 ,   red,  .7   ,  d  ,  2
 E,.2,1.5, .5 ,  gray,       ,  e  ,  1
 F,.1, .5, .7 ,  blue,  .3   ,  f  ,  2
 G, 2,  1, .4 ,  cyan,  .7   ,  g  ,  2
 H, 1,  1, .4 ,yellow,  .7   ,  h  ,  2
```

**`ml_edges.csv`**

```
u,v,label,lw,color,opacity,bend,Direct
A,B, ab  ,.5,red   ,   1   ,  30,false
B,C, bc  ,.7,blue  ,   1   , -60,false
A,E, ae  , 1,green ,   1   ,  45,true
C,E, ce  , 2,orange,   1   ,   0,false
A,A, aa  ,.3,black ,  .5   ,  75,false
C,G, cg  , 1,blue  ,  .5   ,   0,false
E,H, eh  , 1,gray  ,  .5   ,   0,false
F,A, fa  ,.7,red   ,  .7   ,   0,true
D,F, df  ,.7,cyan  ,   1   ,   30,true
F,H, fh  ,.7,purple,   1   ,   60,false
D,G, dg  ,.7,blue  ,  .7   ,   60,false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the reason why it works in the manual but not in your case is that in Ti*k*Z coordinates are global. That is, when the manual compiles, first the examples on p. 32 are compiled, and they create the vertices. That is, the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data/ml_vertices.csv}
id,x,y,size,color,opacity,label,layer
A,0,0,.4,green,.9,a,1
B,1,.7,.6,purple,.5,b,1
C,2,1,.8,orange,.3,c,1
D,2,0,.5,red,.7,d,2
E,.2,1.5,.5,gray,,e,1
F,.1,.5,.7,blue,.3,f,2
G,2,1,.4,cyan,.7,g,2
H,1,1,.4,yellow,.7,h,2
\end{filecontents*} 
\begin{filecontents*}{data/ml_edges.csv}
u,v,label,lw,color,opacity,bend,Direct
A,B,ab,.5,red,1,30,false
B,C,bc,.7,blue,1,-60,false
A,E,ae,1,green,1,45,true
C,E,ce,2,orange,1,0,false
A,A,aa,.3,black,.5,75,false
C,G,cg,1,blue,.5,0,false
E,H,eh,1,gray,.5,0,false
F,A,fa,.7,red,.7,0,true
D,F,df,.7,cyan,1,30,true
F,H,fh,.7,purple,1,60,false
D,G,dg,.7,blue,.7,60,false
\end{filecontents*} 
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[multilayer=3d]
\Vertices[layer=1]{data/ml_vertices.csv}
\Vertices[layer=2]{data/ml_vertices.csv}
\Edges[style=dashed]{data/ml_edges.csv}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[multilayer=3d]
\Edges[vertices=data/ml_vertices.csv, layer={1,2},style=dashed]{data/ml_edges.csv}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why? Only because the coordinates are correctly generated in the first `tikzpicture`. If I comment it out, I reproduce the error you get because then the coordinates do not get defined. I guess you should inform the author of these issues, which some may want to call bugs.

Comment: thankfull again. I will open an issue https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network/ to advise the author and would agree to continue if I have further notes for further clarification.

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah Yes, that's probably useful. Perhaps you can try to convince the author to test each example in a standalone document.

Comment: I will point out the suggestion of using standalone right now within this github issue in order to cover all the examples in the manual. Thank you for this specific advice and if you can explain why the use of standalone is so different and decisive.

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah I tried to explain in my answer that coordinates are global. That is, when you define them in one `tikzpicture` they are are known in the subsequent ones. So the manual only works by accident.

Comment: Of course @marmot understood perfectly, just had no idea of the relationship of standalone format with the use of global settings of a package. I will be keeping an eye on updating this issue on github (https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network/issues/14) as I posted it and having modifications will add them here for everyone to know in the future :)

Comment: Good finding, @marmot! I believe `standalone` was just an example and another class such as `article` would work as well, the point being to test each code sample individually—that is, in its own document without any interference from other examples.

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah You should consider marking marmot's answer as accepted (see “[How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)”).

Comment: @frougon Yes, I do agree with this, of course. "standalone" was meant to indicate "separate document", but you are right in that one may read it as `standalone` class. (And maybe the package author will post a real answer, which can be marked as the accepted one. My post is only to say that Diego does not see ghosts. ;-)

Comment: @frougon I was in doubt whether or not to close the issue as resolved to await author changes on githbub.com but I will take it as resolved. Thankful.

Comment: Thanks. User @marmot explained why the example worked in the manual but not alone and how to make it work, so I consider that he answered the question. The fix in the manual is another thing that we can't expect from people writing answers here. :-)